# "run (a) 1000$ giveaway"

Tags: articles

Is it possible to omit the article in this phrase?

"I decided to run (a) $1000 giveaway"

Is the phrase correct by itself?

Comment: Do you mean “a $1000 giveaway”?

Comment: Take the adjective away.  Would you say “decided to run giveaway “ or “ ... run a giveaway”?

Comment: Note that the dollar sign shows up first and is pronounced second: $1,000 is spoken as "one thousand **dollars**." Your title puts the $ after the amount, the was we say it rather than the standard written form.

Answer (score 2):

No, the article can't be omitted. "I decided to run $1000 giveaway" is grammatically incorrect for the same reason "I decided to run giveaway" is.

Comment: Since this is an answer, you should explain why the article can't be omitted and cite a source. Of course native speakers know intuitively that an article is necessary here, but a great part of the interest of this site is the opportunity to discuss reasons for choices in grammar.

Comment: That's basically what I wanted to hear. Thank you.